# Has Joe Biden made any promises to revert Trump's US pullouts out of global alliances?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, joe-biden

According to [this article](https://theprint.in/world/paris-deal-to-who-the-11-organisations-donald-trumps-us-has-pulled-out-of-weakened/432486/), Donald Trump has managed to pull out US from a series of international organizations such as Trans-Pacific Partnership, Paris Climate Agreement, UNESCO, Iran nuclear deal, WTO.

BBC mentions that Biden's intentions are to revert (some or all of) these pullouts:

> President Trump has praised autocrats and insulted allies. At the top
> of Joe Biden's To-Do list is a full-court press to repair strained
> relationships, especially in Nato, and rejoin global alliances. A
> Biden administration would return to the **World Health Organization** and
> seek to lead an international coronavirus response.

WHO and NATO are the only explicit organization names and I am wondering if all other pullouts will be reverted.

I am interested if Joe Biden or some other official made a more detailed statement related to the pullouts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are varied responses or promises to the various organizations and deals.

#### Strongly Supportive

**Paris Climate Agreement:**

> Joe Biden knows how to stand with America’s allies, stand up to adversaries, and level with any world leader about what must be done. He will not only recommit the United States to the Paris Agreement on climate change – he will go much further than that.

https://joebiden.com/climate-plan/

#### Seems Supportive, but with Alterations

**JCPOA (Iran Nuclear Deal):**

> If Tehran returns to compliance with the deal, President Biden would re-enter the agreement, using hard-nosed diplomacy and support from our allies to strengthen and extend it, while more effectively pushing back against Iran’s other destabilizing activities.

https://joebiden.com/americanleadership/

**TPP**

> “I would not rejoin the TPP as it was initially put forward. I would insist that we renegotiate,” Biden said during the Democratic debate in Detroit [in August 2019].

https://www.politico.com/newsletters/morning-trade/2019/08/01/biden-says-he-would-renegotiate-tpp-464000

#### Possibly Supportive, but with Definite Alterations

**WTO**

> Biden believes the WTO needs “a lot of reform,” [Biden adviser Tony Blinken] also said the body can sometimes be “an effective tool.”

https://www.politico.com/news/2020/09/22/biden-tariffs-adviser-420096

#### Can't Find a Statement from Biden

**UNESCO**

> [Biden] is expected to take steps such as...rejoining UNESCO and the United Nations Human Rights Commission.

https://www.dailysabah.com/opinion/op-ed/joe-bidens-foreign-policy-and-turkey

---

#### Bonus

*This may or may not belong to the "global alliances" category, but I feel compelled to include it, because it seems to have almost completely been forgotten by the public*

**Muslim Ban**

> "I [Joe Biden] will end the Muslim ban on day one. Day one."

https://www.cnbc.com/2020/07/20/biden-pledges-to-end-trumps-muslim-ban-on-his-first-day-in-office.html